# CSS3 Transform - handling the after-hovering behavior

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

In this CSS3 code when I hover on the class it rotates by 360 degree, but when I go away from the class it back as it was .

The question: how can i make the class rotating even when I go away ?

The code below :

```
.class{  transition: transform 1s; }
.class:hover{  transform: rotate(360deg); }
```

Comment: If you switch it to an animation and set up the animation to run `infinite` then that should work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to play with the `transition` attribute on both the `normal` and `hovered` states.

**Running Demo**: [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9wdfG/1/)

```
<div class="both" > I'll animate on hover and on blur </div>
<div class="hover"> I'll animate on hover only        </div>
<div class="blur" > I'll animate on blur only         </div>
```

- **Both**

  ```
  Normal ----1s----> Hovered ----1s----> Normal
  ```

  A transition of 1s always applied to `transform`, that is executed on hover; then it will work in both directions.

  ```
  .both {
      transition: transform 1s;
  }

  .both:hover {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  ```
- **Hover**

  ```
  Normal ----1s----> Hovered ----0s----> Normal
  ```

  It will use 1s of transition to reach the hovered state, but it will use a 0s transition to reach the normal state **from** the hovered state

  ```
  .hover {    
      transition: transform 0s;
  }

  .hover:hover {
      transition: transform 1s;
      transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  ```
- **Blur**

  ```
  Normal ----0s----> Hovered ----1s----> Normal
  ```

  It will use 0s of `transition` to reach the hovered state, but it will use a 1s `transition` to reach the normal state **from** the hovered state

  ```
  .blur {    
      transition: transform 1s;
  }

  .blur:hover {
      transition: transform 0s;
      transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

there is not a direct and pure css answer, you should use js or jquery.
this is the jquery version:

```
$('.class').on('mouseEnter', function(){
    $(this).trigger('hover');
});
```

**BUT there is some other ways to do things like this**